# migrate:refresh and migrate:reset gives Class '' not found error in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I used the command "php artisan migrate:reset" and "php artisan migrate:refresh" both gives the error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class '' not found
```

I also need to remove column from table using migration in laravel 5.1, please guide me or send me any reference links.
I attached my error screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2fD4.jpg) .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get an issue like this I usually dump the autoloader:

`composer dump-autoload`

To remove a column from the database you can either remove it from you migration and run:

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

Which is usually fine in a development environment, but you will lose any data in your database, so it's a good idea to set up some seeders if you want to do it this way.

Otherwise, you can create a new migration to simply drop your column using:

`php artisan make:migration drop_my_column_from_my_table --table=my_table`

You would then do something like:

```
Schema::table('my_table', function ($table) {
    $table->dropColumn('my_column');
});
```

and run you migration as normal:

`php artisan migrate`

Comment: Yeah, its very helpful... Thanks craig_h :)